# What is the best way to send XML data to webservices jaxws

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

What is the best way to send XML data to web services jax-ws?

One of the way I could make out is to convert xml into String from client side and send it as a String to WebService.

I don't think this is the best way / best practice .

Comment: can some one refer me with send xml from .net to java client when the webservice is publish with java and .net is calling the web service if i send it as string , or byte[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the serialized Java objects directly.

Comment: What about using XStream to serialize it and then instead writting it to file add it to StringBuffer then send .

Comment: And why would you want to do that?

Comment: It should be XML doc that going to be uploaded.

Comment: When you serialize objects, JAXB will create the correct wsdl file for you. The data is transfered as XML, so its the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use framework that supports web-service standards. For Java try [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) or [Apache Axis 2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/).

Answer (score 0):

Why are using XML would be the first question.

I would say take a look at the google protocol buffer, you will be able create a .proto file same as you create xsd and then you will be able to generate code from that proto file into different languages, the way you send over to the webservice is just takes the bytes array out of the google proto object and send it.

Answer (score 0):

**Encode** --> **Escape/ Wrap** with **CDATA** --> set value to a string --> pass as a parameter to webservice/remote method as defined in your wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the need to do so such XML request -response.. Though there could be varied views on this.. at times the need is  defined by the application/package that we work on ..

1 good article which i found on this 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/implementing-jax-ws-web

Hope this helps

Samant