# What is the best practice to send XML data embedded in a SOAP message?

Tags: java, xml, soap, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS Web-Service which accepts some basic data and a String which is supposed to contains the content of a whole XML file.
In the first time I though I can just put this XML in my SOAP request as a CDATA section like this:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
    ...
      <contentData>
    <![CDATA[
      <my>
        <xml>
          <here>
            ...
          </here>
        </xml>
      </my>
    ]]>
       </contentData>
       ...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But the issue is that my XML data contains as well some CDATA sections and it is not working like this as nested CDATA are not allowed ([W3School reference](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_cdatasection.asp)).

What would be the best practice to send such data?

- solution 1: escaping all special characters in order to have `&lt;` and
  `&gt;` (among others)
- solution 2: convert my XML in base64 and decode
  it in my web-service
- another solution welcome

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041078/what-is-the-best-way-to-send-xml-data-to-webservices-jaxws) but serialising the Java object is not an option as the XML data are generated by another side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely prefer Solution 2, encoding and decoding Base64 formats.

Comment: Thanks it looks to be the best solution for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer:

[Use XmlDocument as param type in the Web-Service, rather than string](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1437285)

This is what the Web-Service I am communicating with is using.

Comment: That would be the best choice when you have the hand on the web-service contract (WSDL). But in my case I was using an existing service that I was not able to change.

Comment: link is broken, can you update your answer with more details?