# How to send an XML request to a web service

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I have generated web service classes by using `wsimport` and now I am supposed to send a XML request (particular format given) to this webservice which return a XML response and then I can use that XML response on my side. How do you create this custom XML request which I am supposed to send to webservice. Any documentation available there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041078/what-is-the-best-way-to-send-xml-data-to-webservices-jaxws some one already answered it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to do that..

one of them is using [HttpClient from Apache](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)  and executing a POST like this

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://jakarata.apache.org/");
NameValuePair[] data = {
  new NameValuePair("user", "joe"),
  new NameValuePair("password", "bloggs")
};
post.setRequestBody(data);
post.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/xhtml+xml");
// execute method and handle any error responses.
...
InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
// handle response.
```

Comment: How does this create XML request?

Comment: you only have to dispatch a request which the body is filled with an XML string as the parameter.. `new NameValuePair("param", "my xml string")`